# Как в tkinter отобразить html код диаграммы сайта

Tags: python, html, tkinter

Есть сайт на котором есть диаграмма, мне нужно еë спарсить и отобразить в окне ткинтера. Я нашел библиотеку tkinterhtml но она выводит только текст.
Вот эту диаграму мне нужно отображать в окне ткинтера:
[image: диаграма]

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел способ который решит эту проблему. Нужно спарсить svg элемент в файл .svg и конвертировать его в png